# How to get the delta(changed) fields in user of group by using Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory

How to get the delta(changed)  fields in user of group by using Graph Api. I Am using this URL  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta/?$filter= id eq 'efa699db-d364-4f1f-8d7d-e77ec7444222'/&$expand=members . with this i'm only getting ID value but i need all the fields.

Answer (score -1):

In the delta request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=id eq 'groupid'&$expand=members`, it only returns the member id. You could add the `$select`, but it just returns the specified properties for the group, and not for the member.

[image]

Comment: Yes that is what i'm facing the issue .. I need all the members of the group with all the fields(properties). Is there any way that i can pull all the properties of members within the group when i did the delta on it.

Comment: You are repeating the question  itself rather than trying to answer